# How to " no-flood-fill " a texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

By `No-Flood-Fill` I mean **filling like in paint**. A fill brush in blender **fills the entire object**. This is not the result I am looking for. However, I want to **fill only instead of a certain color**?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Fill Tool in the 2d Image Editor and you can then use the Thresh hold setting to dial in your desired tolerance. This threshold feature is not possible as of yet in the 3D view in Texture Paint mode, as it is a different process for painting under the hood. I believe that google search should have brought you to a thread here if I am not mistaken(I made that picture).

Answer (score 0):

Hum... There's supposed to be a Threshold option allowing you to manage that, but... I can't find it myself anymore...

I just found a picture on google :

[image]

Dunno why it's gone. Probably shouldn't be, maybe a bug.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, I'm seeing the same thing. I can't find the threshold setting under fill. And I'm doing it on the 2D side. Is this a bug?!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174101/trying-to-find-the-threshold-setting-for-the-fill-brush-in-2-8?rq=1

I found this link, maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, it's back since then