# Trying to find the threshold setting for the Fill brush in 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

I'm drawing pixel art onto textures using texture paint and I want to fill in a certain area of the texture with a solid color with zero tolerance for overwriting any adjacent pixels that aren't the exact same color. It appears that 2.79 had the setting directly under the color picker as seen in this question: [How to " no-flood-fill " a texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127742/how-to-no-flood-fill-a-texture/127748#comment292380_127748)

But I can't find the same setting in 2.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fill Threshold" is now in the "Advanced" menu :
[image: picture]